# Reading sys.maxint from file

Tags: python, file

I have some Python program that reads certain values from a file.

*File example:*

```
0
4
5
6
```

The code to parse each line is as follows:

```
    s = f2.readline()
    p = int(s)
```

I am trying to pass `sys.maxint` in the file instead as follows:

```
0
sys.maxint
5
6
```

One of the ways to do so is to check `if (s=='sys.maxint')` as especial case in the code.

I wonder if there is another *neat* way to do so?

Comment: You *could* use `eval()`, but I personally wouldn't.

Comment: @NPE: Yes, you're right, especially with "but I personally wouldn't"

Comment: Because it's dangerous, slow and too general.

Comment: What's so important about `sys.maxint` that you want to specify it in the file? And what's wrong with manually typing in that value? Where does the file come from?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel It is an open source code, so I want the least modification in it.

Comment: The *data file* is "an open source code"?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why `if` isn't "neat". In my opinion it is the obvious solution. If you really want to do it without an `if`, you can do this (with an unnecessary string representation):

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
import sys

for s in (s.strip () for s in open ('test', 'r') ):
    p = int (s.replace ('sys.maxint', str (sys.maxint) ) )
    print (p)
```

I personally would keep the `if`:

```
for s in (s.strip () for s in open ('test', 'r') ):
    p = sys.maxint if s == 'sys.maxint' else int (s)
    print (p)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a dictionary of look-up values, e.g.

```
import sys

constants = {"sys.maxint" : sys.maxint, "meaning_of_life": 42}

with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f2:
        s = line.rstrip("\n")
        try:
            p = int(s)
        except ValueError, ve:
            p = constants.get(s)
            if p is None:
                raise ve
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use eval function. Although it will serve the purpose, it should be used with caution.

```
    Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Sep 27 2012, 21:16:52) 
    [GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> a = eval('0')
    >>> import sys
    >>> a = eval('sys.maxint')
    >>> a
    2147483647
    >>>
```

Comment: "with caution"? i.e. you parse its input before calling?